# ASK, Istio on gke error installation, galley + pilot run but getting error on logs

Tags: google-kubernetes-engine, istio

I got some problem when trying istio installation through GKE istio. I had installed istio, and got some problems: on pods galley + pilot seems to run, but when checking on logs I got some error and not enable to proper function on istio-proxy. gke version istio was:

```
image: gke.gcr.io/istio/pilot:1.1.16-gke.0
image: gke.gcr.io/istio/pilot:1.1.16-gke.0
```

and this my error from galley:

[error on galley-istio](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WcyYd.jpg)

and this from pilot:
[error on pilot-istio](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XeHIa.jpg)

Comment: Please do not use screenshots of error - copy and paste them directly to your question.

Answer (score 0):

For the first error:

Galley:

Error reading mesh config as json. unknow field"sidecarToTelemtrySessionAffinity" in

It seems you need to check this:

Stackdriver server expects a time series only comes from one source, which means session affinity needs to be enabled between sidecar and telemetry server.

To achieve that, you need to set "sidecarToTelemetrySessionAffinity: true" in mesh config and add "sessionAffinity: ClientIP" to istio-telemetry service (Istio from x.x.x.x).

For the second error:

Failed to create a new MCP sink stream: rpc error: code = Unavailable desc = all SubConns are in TransientFailure, latest connection error: connection error: desc = "transport: Error while dialing dial tcp:i/o timeout"
I am looking for this error in some documents that I have. I hope found it soon.

My 2cents.

Also, you always have more details.

[Policies and Telemetry](https://archive.istio.io/v1.2/docs/reference/config/policy-and-telemetry/)